# Salesforce Integration with External Scheduler

Tags: rest-api, api, batch, externalid

I'm currently working with a customer that is interested in launching Salesforce Batch jobs from an external scheduler. I was thinking about the following

```
- Create a global interface 

    global interface TWSJob {
        void execute();
    }

- Create a RESTful web service

    @RestResource(urlMapping='/TWSSubmitApexClass/*')
    global with sharing class TWSSubmitApexClass{
        @HttpGet
        global static void doGet() {
            RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
            RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
            String apexClass = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            Type t = Type.forName(apexClass);
            TWSJob s = (TWSJob)t.newInstance();
            s.execute();
        }
    }

- Create a RESTful web service (/TWSMonitorAPEXJob) to monitor the progress using AsyncApexJob.
```

What do you guys think?

Many thanks.

Miguel

Answer (score 3):

You're not actually executing a batch. You're just running its execute function. This would limit your class to the normal REST API governor limits. Instead, you should a virtual class:

```
global virtual class BatchableObjectClass implements Database.Batchable<Object>, Database.Stateful {
    global virtual Iterable<Object> start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return null;
    }
    global virtual void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, Object[] items) {

    }
    global virtual void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

    }
}
```

From here, your code has to change slightly to support this change:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/TWSSubmitApexClass/*')
global with sharing class TWSSubmitApexClass{
    @HttpGet
    global static void doGet() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        String apexClass = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        Type t = Type.forName(apexClass);
        Object s = t.newInstance();
        Database.executeBatch((Database.Batchable<Object>)s);
    }
}
```

This class handles normal "query type" projects and "iterable" type projects. The only downside is that your code will be required to cast generic objects and sobjects into concrete objects on the receiving end. This will only add a couple of lines of code, so it shouldn't be a big deal.

Note that for query types, you'll have to cast the query locator into an `Iterable<Object>` return type, and you'll have to cast the `Object[] items` into a `SObject[] records` variable to get at the SObject functions contained therein (you should also be able to cast directly to a known type, such as `Account[]`, if you know the type beforehand).

### Updates

- Updated code to reflect a single virtual class instead of two-- the latter appears redundant.

Comment: Would you need two classes for Iterable vs SObject? Pretty sure you can use the Iterable one for both.

Comment: I actually tried a single class before I posted this code. If you try, you end up with two functions with a signature `start(Database.batchableContext)` (the return type doesn't factor into the signature), so you get a duplicate function error.

Comment: I'm sure you only need the first/Iterable and that would work for QueryLocator too which I guess is also Iterable?

Comment: While all `QueryLocator`s are `Iterable`s, not all `Iterable`s are `QueryLocator`s. At least in previous incarnations of Apex Code, returning a normal `Iterable` resulted in the system calling `next()`/`hasNext()` repeatedly, resulting in a maximum number of records it could parse-- far less than the 50,000,000 that a true `QueryLocator` can access. If that's no longer true (or if I'm just hallucinating), then I see no reason why the first form won't necessary work (but then again, not all `Object`s are `SObject`s, either...

Comment: It requires some extra casting, but you're right. It appears to work normally. You can therefore reduce the total solution down to just a single virtual class. I'm pretty sure this wouldn't have worked in an earlier version of Apex Code (I tried it once...), but it appears fully functional now.